# Who provides centripetal acceleration to moving car in non-uniform circular motion when net acceleration is provided by static friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

I can't understand while solving the question of non-uniform circular motion, please help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

First, this explains the simpler case of uniform circular motion. [Why does the friction act on the inward direction when a car makes a turn on a level road?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/495120/37364)

Non uniform motion isn't that much different. We just need to keep track of two different accelerations. Acceleration is a vector. That means we can think about the two accelerations separately, and then add them to get the total.

The first acceleration is centripetal acceleration. It is just like the uniform case. It points toward the center and keeps the car turning in a circle. It is caused by the friction between the tires and the road. The magnitude grows if the car speeds up and shrinks if it slows down. If the car is traveling in a circle of radius $r$ at speed $v$, then you know $a_{centripetal} = v^2/r$. It changes the direction of the car, but does not speed or slow it.

The second acceleration speeds or slows the car. It is supplied by the engine or brakes. These push the car forward or hold it back. They do not change its direction. If you step on the gas the car will go faster. The direction is forward. If the car follows a curved path, that is determined by the steering wheel, not the engine.

Comment: I'm not sure if the centripetal force (acceleration) is caused by friction. I think it's the reaction force of the material on which the car accelerates that's responsible. Is this friction?

Comment: I think you have the idea. The name might just be a vocabulary issue. Forces always occur in equal and opposite pairs. Sometimes people say one is the force and the other is the reaction. Sometimes that makes sense. When a weight sits on a table gravity presses the weight on the table, and the table pushes back with a reaction force. In this case, the road and the tire exert equal and opposite forces on each other because of friction. This is different than a tire and ice. I call both of these friction, and you call one friction and the other reaction.

Comment: But imagine an object moving inside a spherical shell, without friction. What keeps the object moving in a circle? Is it friction? Isn't friction (and its reaction force) always parallel to the direction of the velocity, while the centripetal force is always perpendicular to it? Though I see now, in the example you give, of course, this perpendicular force is delivered by friction, but for the case where no friction is involved this perpendicular force is not caused by friction. That is, for an object constrained by a wall or something.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For an object constrained to move in a circle by a spherical shell, centripetal force would be supplied by a reaction force. I talked about friction from tires on the road because you were talking about a car.

Answer (score 0):

The same static friction can be resolved in two components, one along radial direction and one along tangential direction.The tangential component is responsible for changing magnitude of speed of the body while radial component provides centripetal acceleration.